# Feller property for Ito diffusion with Lipschitz coefficients

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider the following Ito diffusion $X_t$ satisfying

$$dX_t=b(X_t)dt+\sigma(X_t)dB_t,\quad X_0=x\in \mathbb{R}^n,$$

with Lipschitz coefficients $b,\sigma$.

It can be shown that if $g$ is bounded and continuous, then $u(x)=E^x[g(X_t)]$ is continuous. So any Ito diffusion is $C_b$-[Feller continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feller-continuous_process).

However, some books define Feller property to be if  $g$ is continuous and vanishes at infinity, then $u$ is continuous and vanishes at infinity.

It seems that Brownian Motion satisfies this property. I have also shown that one dimensional Ito diffusion has Feller property using a sufficient condition given in Lorenzi's book.

May I know whether in general the Ito diffusion $X_t$ (SDE with global Lipschitz coefficients) satisfying this property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hypotheses:

1. $b$ and $\sigma$ are globally Lipschitz continuous;
2. $\sigma(x) \sigma(x)^T$ is positive definite for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$;

one can prove that the semigroup $P_t$ associated to $X$ is, in fact, *strong* Feller, meaning that for any $t \ge 0$ the semigroup $P_t$ maps $B_b(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (bounded functions) to $C_b(\mathbb{R}^n)$ ( bounded and continuous functions).  This result is typical of SDEs with non-degenerate noise.  See, e.g., Chapter 12 of Giuseppe Da Prato (2014). **Introduction to Stochastic Analysis and Malliavin Calculus.**  The Feller property is weaker, and as you say, just requires that for any $t \ge 0$ the semigroup $P_t$ maps $C_b(\mathbb{R}^n)$ into itself.

Some books discuss the related, but different, concept of Feller-Dynkin processes where $C_b(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is replaced with $C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$, the set of continuous functions vanishing at infinity. This overloading of terminology is unfortunate.  Since we have the inclusion $ C_0(\mathbb{R}^n) \subset C_b(\mathbb{R}^n)$, the notion of a Feller process is a bit more general than a Feller-Dynkin process.